# error ! No valid credentials source for S3 bucket , Terraform AWS docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, terraform

I 'am trying to setup terraform to create ressources ,
I need to add an AWS S3 bucket for storing terraform state , a dynamodb table for handling state-locking and  an AWS ECR repository, so we can build and push our images.
I will setup project to run terraform using docker-compose to avoid dependencies
I"ve created the s3 bucket ,and I've enabled versionning in it, so every time we add a new file to the bucket ,it will store the previous version of that file, so if we update the file , we
can revert to previous version of it.

I didn't install the terraform in my localmachine
I have executed my credentials with aws-vault with "aws-vault exec fouednajari --duration=12h"

[the docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CeiJ.png)

[the main.tf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b4Dj.png)

[this is my ~/.aws/config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPiij.png)

[this is my ~/.aws/credentials file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH3cw.png)

But I have got this error when trying to run my docker-compose command to initiate terraform .

[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoH5Y.png)

please help me ,

I HAVE SOLVED THIS BY ADDING THE ACCESS_KEY AND THE SECRET KEY IN THE BACKEND AND THE PROVIDER "AWS" SECTION AND THEN I'VE EXPORTED THE VARIABLES WITH THE REGION VARIABLE !!!!!.
THANK YOU GOD !

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform looks for credentials in the following order:

1. Static credentials
2. Environment variables
3. Shared credentials/configuration file
4. CodeBuild, ECS, and EKS Roles
5. EC2 Instance Metadata Service (IMDS and IMDSv2)

Try to configure your credentials with "aws configure" command or export those vars to the environment

Comment: I have executern "aws configure " before but still not working

Comment: please delete the aws vars in the provider section so it will look at the env vars

Comment: I have deleted them but almost still having the same error : " Error configuring the backend "s3": No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider."

Comment: Please show the output of "env | grep AWS"

Comment: Thank you Mr. JohnMops , I have solved this issue by adding the access.key and secret.key in the backend and the the provider section of main.tf and export them after that

Comment: Np at all, have fun :)